# jQuery not displaying form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below jQuery script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
        $(".selectInput").hide();
        $("#"this.value).show();
    });
});

</script>
```

It is suppose to display a form field when a dropdown is selected. But its not. I am guessing its probably because the html generated is

```
<option value="Title 1" value="1">Title 1</option>
```

But if I change the abover jquery code to this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
        $(".selectInput").hide();
        $("#1").show();
    });
});

</script>
```

It works. 
But I have about 10 different option ids. How do I fix it?

I hope I am making sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$("#"this.value).show();
```

to

```
$("#"+this.value).show();
```

and remove the duplicate `value` attribute, that is change

```
<option value="Title 1" value="1">Title 1</option>
```

to

```
<option value="1">Title 1</option>
```

Comment: Well, there's a `+`. This changes from a syntax error to a string concatenation.

Comment: i thought it must be a integer to string thing

Comment: try console.log(this.value) to see this famous value. There's no need to convert from integer to string.

Comment: yep it works now. if i may ask for one more favor. How i can update the text box using jquery and with manually text/provided by me, for the same question ?

Comment: To change a textbox use `$('#myTextBoxId').val('new text');`

Answer (score 1):

you should write.

```
  $("#"+this.value).show();
```

Comment: yeah but its not working. its not showing the text field. I am assuming it has something to do with integer and string values.

Answer (score 1):

change it to 
     $("#"+this.value).show();

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as adding the "+" between # and this.value

Answer (score 1):

You need to concate the string correctly:

```
$("#" + this.value).show();
```

Also, there's a error in your HTML markup, it should be this:

```
<option title="Title 1" value="1">Title 1</option>
```

Instead of this:

```
<option value="Title 1" value="1">Title 1</option>
```

where, you have two values, which is causing issue in your case.

Comment: right,but thats how it is generated. If thats the case, do you know how do i adjust my jquery script to accept title/strings instead for instnace `Pick a reason` instead of `0` ?

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not contain a string but contains an object: the element itself. `this` does not have a property called `value` so `this.value` will not work. You have to access the child that has been selected either by `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` or via jQuery `$(this).val()`. This should be a working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
        $(".selectInput").hide();
        var element = $(this).val();
        $("#" + element).show();
    });
});
```